# Entity Framework one-to-many Configuration

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I currently have the following database structure:

- `TableA` (`itemCode int, itemCategoryCode int, itemDescription description`)
- `TableB` (`id int, itemCode int, itemCategoryCode int`)

TableA's PK is `(itemCode, itemCategoryCode)`. TableB's PK is `id` and FK is `(itemCode, itemCategoryCode)`.

I need to set up EF such that i have a one to many relationship between TableA and TableB. And such that when I grab the object from TableB the navigational property of TableA is populated.

How do I set up my POCO classes with annotations to achieve this and/or fluent API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Data Annotations:

Table A:

```
public class TableA {

  [Key, Column(Order=0)]
  public int itemCode { get; set; }

  [Key, Column(Order=1)]  
  public int itemCategoryCode { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<TableB> TableBs { get; set; }
}
```

TableB:

```
public class TableB {

  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("TableARecord"), Column(Order=1)]
  public int itemCode { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey("TableARecord"), Column(Order=2)]  
  public int itemCategoryCode { get; set; }

  public virtual TableA TableARecord { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: When I applied the annotations it worked. however when I do a join it on some other table and bring back the object from the context, the property is not populated. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

just add a Virtual Collection property to the "Many" class,
and a property of type "One" to your "Many" class
see below code from http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

```
public class Student
    {
        public Student() { }

        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }

        public virtual Standard Standard { get; set; }
    }

    public class Standard
    {
        public Standard()
        {
            StudentsList = new List<Student>();
        }
        public int StandardId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```